# copy() does not copy file and throws no errors

Tags: php, copy

I have this code, which copies a PDF to the server (from another server I run, not connected though)

```
if($json->result == "success"){
    if(!@copy($json->message, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/web/pdfs/".$fileName.".pdf")){
        $errors= error_get_last();
        var_dump($errors);
       die('FAILED TO COPY '.$json->message.' to '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'web/pdfs/'.$fileName.'.pdf');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it does not copy, but it also does not throw any errors, as `$errors` is empty.

The output:

```
NULL FAILED TO COPY http://xxx.domain.com/files/b6ab5aa0b641b6bdf49b55d2ceab39f4e16cfe51.pdf to /is/htdocs/wp12461140_9GNPYMXV7T/www/web/pdfs/98a23c8e.pdf
```

`98a23c8e.pdf` does not exists (yet), the `pdfs` folder has CHMOD777.

Any ideas why it's failing or even why there is no error?

Comment: the remote server offers access to this file `b6ab5aa0b641b6bdf49b55d2ceab39f4e16cfe51.pdf ` in directory `files` ?

Comment: What does "offers access" mean? I can copy the URL and the file gets downloaded, yes it is accessible...

Comment: What var_dump is printing? Show some errors

Comment: so maybe copy() is disable on server. Could you check it with `function_exists('copy')`?

Comment: Returns `1` so it is enabled on the server where I copy it to. Does it need to be enabled on the remote server as well? Any other options that need to be turned on?